# Glossaries: how to disable indexing locally, self reference inside the definition?

Tags: glossaries

**How to disable indexing locally?**

Requirement: that `\Gls{foo}` inside `fancyhead` not be indexed, such that only page 1, instead of 1 & 2, be displayed next to "Foo" under "Glossary".

[image]

**Self reference inside the definition**

For entry `foo`, how would I call `\Gls{foo}`, or some variant, inside `name=`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makenoidxglossaries

\newglossaryentry{foo}
{
%  name={\Gls*{foo}}, % ERROR: Improper alphabetic constant.
%  name={\Glsentrytext{foo}}, % ERROR: Improper alphabetic constant.
  name={Foo},
  text={foo},
  description={ }
}

\newglossaryentry{bar}
{
%  name={\Gls*{bar}},
  name={Bar},
  text={bar},
  description={ }
}


\usepackage{fancyhdr}%-------------------------------------------------
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[c]{\Gls*{foo}}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}

\Gls{foo}

\newpage

\Gls{bar}

\printnoidxglossaries

\end{document}
```